# In Testcase statment gives error after upgrading the springboot version from 2.1.7 to 2.6.4

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit5, assertj

After updating the **Spring Boot version to 2.6.4** I am getting error in the test case while in its old **version 2.1.7** working fine

```
@Test
fun `Should include id in all outbound requests`() {
    (authenticationSource as TestAuthenticationSource).setCoordinatorToken()
    val request = PersonSearch().apply {
        firstName = “Xyz”
        lastName = “Abc”
    }
    val oid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

    client
            .post()
            .uri("/v/search/outbound")
            .headers {
                it.setBearerAuth("fakeToken")
                it.set(CORRELATION_ID, oid)
            }
            .body(Mono.just(request), PersonSearch::class.java)
            .exchange()

    assertThat(server.requestCount).isEqualTo(2)
   // The bellow line give error while it was working fine in previous version 
    assertThat(server.takeAllRequests()).allSatisfy { assertThat(it.headers.toMultimap()).containsEntry(CORRELATION_ID, listOf(oid)) }

  // Trying in this way as well
    assertThat(server.takeAllRequests()).allSatisfy { it -> assertThat(it.headers.toMultimap()).containsEntry(CORRELATION_ID, listOf(oid)) }
}
```

In **error** is shows the first line as -

```
Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
public open fun allSatisfy(requirements: Consumer<in RecordedRequest!>!): ObjectArrayAssert<RecordedRequest!>! defined in org.assertj.core.api.ObjectArrayAssert
public open fun allSatisfy(requirements: ThrowingConsumer<in RecordedRequest!>!): ObjectArrayAssert<RecordedRequest!>! defined in org.assertj.core.api.ObjectArrayAssert
```

While it throws same **exception** Message when running -

```
Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public open fun allSatisfy(p0: Consumer<in RecordedRequest!>!): ObjectArrayAssert<RecordedRequest!>! defined in org.assertj.core.api.ObjectArrayAssert
public open fun allSatisfy(p0: ThrowingConsumer<in RecordedRequest!>!): ObjectArrayAssert<RecordedRequest!>! defined in org.assertj.core.api.ObjectArrayAssert
```

Comment: Could you please post the error? :)

Comment: @y434y I have updated Error/exception details

Answer (score 3):

You are likely hitting https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/2357.

For workarounds see:

- https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/2357#issuecomment-1103942325
- https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/2357#issuecomment-1117013186
- https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/2357#issuecomment-1087445548

Answer (score 0):

As in this url [assertj-core/issues/2357](https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/2357) suggested by @Joel Costigliola I have made small changes just added **Consumer** key after allSatisfy to eliminate the ambiguity.

```
assertThat(server.takeAllRequests())
    .allSatisfy( 
                Consumer {  // added part
                        assertThat(it.headers.toMultimap()).containsEntry(CORRELATION_ID, listOf(cId))
                    }
    )
```